# Do I need Nautilus on RedHat / CentOS / Scientific Linux 6?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, scientific-linux, centos

I've found that Nautilus causes problems in my Scientific Linux 6 desktop (specifically it gets into an infinite loop opening the file manager at startup). While those problems are interesting in their own right, it got me wondering if I really need it for anything. When I do this:

```
sudo yum remove nautilus
```

the problem goes away, and since I never interact with the GUI file manager this doesn't seem like a problem. Will this bite me later on? Are there some hidden uses for Nautilus other than browsing files with a GUI?

Comment: it seems that `evince` uses nautilus somehow, so I've reinstalled it... fun while it lasted...

Answer (score 3):

There isn't anything specific to Nautilus that you will need.

The one thing worth mentioning is that Nautilus can be used to visit GVFS locations, such as `computer://`. However, you can probably replace Nautilus with the `gvfs-*` family of tools should you need it.

Comment: If you don't need to use a GUI then no you can safely remove Nautilus.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a problem removing nautilus - I had the same problem and removed it. I simply used dolphin for the time being. The problem with nautilus was introduced with an update yesterday and has since been fixed. You should be able to run a yum update for a resolution.